# basic set builder notation question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was attempting my textbook questions, as shown below, and im currently unsure how the answer is derived

$U = \{ r \in Z |  2 \le r \le -2\}$
Answer sheet: "The set has no element"

$V = \{ s \in Z |  s > 2 \text{ or } s < 3\}$
Answer sheet: "Z (every integer is in the set)"

For the first part, shouldn't it be $U = \{\dots,-2, 2,\dots\}$, since $r$ is an element of all integer, and is lesser than $-2$, but bigger than $2$

For the second question, I was thinking that it shouldn't exist as it is between $2$ and $3$, and is an integer

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$ The first set is empty because if an integer $r\le -2$, then $r$ is negative and thus can't be $\ge 2$. If the integer $r\ge 2$, then $r$ is positive and thus can't be $\le -2$.

$2.$ The second set consists of all the integers because every integer only has to satisfy one of the two conditions. Either that integer has to be greater than $2$ or less than $3$. And every integer greater than $2$ is in the set. And every integer less than or equal to $2$ is also in the set as all those integers are less than $3$.

Hope this clears it up!